# SSIS new line delimited columns with set number of fields

Tags: c#, oracle, file-io, ssis, output

I am making an interface which selects data from an Oracle PL SQL database and then needs to create a text file which is line delimited; each field is on a new line, and each record is a fixed 25 fields. An example of 5 lines of a file would be (line numbers just for reference):

1. 14-08-2013
2. GBP
3. 30
4. 14.99
5. *null field*
6. *null field*
7. 449.70

The file will have a mixture of populated and blank null values but each one will always be 25 lines before starting again. There are no current row delimiters as such, only that after the 25th line, the 26th line will be the first line of the next record.

End of file is signaled by an additional blank line, so if there is 1 record there will be 26 lines (25 fields + 1 blank line) and if there are 2 records there will be 51 lines and so on.

Does anyone know how I can configure a SSIS data destination to output data in such a manner as described above, or any other ways to achieve such an outcome?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Steve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving this using the configurations in the flat file manager. Putting my column delimiter as {CR}{LF} (new line) and leaving row delimiter blank. I had to cheat a bit here because obviously the row delimiter could not be the same as the text qualifier (which also needed to be blank), so I set the text qualifier as ' and then disabled it on each output field.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this:

`select col1||chr(13)||chr(10)||col2||chr(13)||chr(10)`...and so on, and spool this to a file.